# Highchart heatmap plot x-axis on time and y-axis on string

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap

Actually, I was trying to create a heatmap which will show each task time taken to execute in a heatmap.
So basically x-axis will have time in datetime format.y-axis will have each task name and every point will have value which is the time taken to execute the task.
In simple i have formatted my json where data is coming in format

```
[{datetime,stage name,value}]
```

So my xCategory will look like

```
xCategory=[1527657415000,..some datetime]
```

my yCategory is 
   yCategories=["Stage"...]
and series.data=[[0,0,12],[0,1,12]..]

My chart

```
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart('chart', {
chart: {
  type: 'heatmap'
},

xAxis: {
//  categories: xCategories,
 type: 'datetime',
 dateTimeLabelFormats:
  {
    month: '%e. %b',
    year: '%b'
  },

 },

 yAxis: {
//  categories: yCategories
},

plotOptions: {
 series: {
   colorByPoint: true
  }
},

 series: series

});
```

But it is not coming up properly.

Comment: I'm not quite sure you've decided on either using categories or datetime? Also, "not coming up properly" is not well defined. What is happening/isn't happening, and do you get any error output?

Comment: @HalvorStrand I am plotting datetime. On x-axis datetime coming properly but on y-axis nothing is coming up apart from some random numbers.New to HighChart ,not sure what i am doing

Answer (score 0):

In `heatmap` chart type each point occupies the same space, so value data can be only represented by color or by label. If you use `datetime` xAxis type, you must remember to set right `colsize` property.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        plotBorderWidth: 1
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
        categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
        title: null
    },
    colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        minColor: '#FFFFFF',
        maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Sales per employee',
        borderWidth: 1,
        colsize: 60 * 60 * 1000,
        data: [
            [1527657415000, 0, 10],
            [1527657415000, 1, 19],
            [1527657415000, 2, 8],
            [1527657415000, 3, 24],
            [1527657415000, 4, 67],
            [1527661015000, 0, 92],
            [1527661015000, 1, 58],
            [1527661015000, 2, 78],
            [1527661015000, 3, 117],
            [1527661015000, 4, 48],
            [1527661015000, 0, 35],
            [1527661015000, 1, 15],
            [1527661015000, 2, 123],
            [1527661015000, 3, 64],
            [1527661015000, 4, 52],
            [1527664615000, 0, 72],
            [1527664615000, 1, 132],
            [1527664615000, 2, 114],
            [1527664615000, 3, 19],
            [1527664615000, 4, 16]
        ],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000'
        }
    }]
});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zhxyerd1/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.colsize